# Can this app be done in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios

I have to build an app in iOS and Android.
 
**I need to know if this app can be done... is this a doable app?**.

**App requirements**
The app should start automatically when the user opens a browser in his/her cell phone.
Or the app could start with the Operative System and be executed all the time in the background.
The app will detect when a browser is open and the app will read the browser's window content (html or text) and then the app will show a form if a tracking number (from usps, ups, fedex, etc) is found.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, to start with, this app is impossible to write.  There's no way to know when a browser is opened, or get the text of the webpage being displayed.  Nor should there be-  it would be a massive security hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost impossible to accomplish, at least on iOS. You wont't be able to start an app from the browser and furthermore receive the HTML content. However you could allow the user to enter the URL within your app and then parse the webpage.

In general you could use PhoneGap for developing an hybrid app. Nevertheless I rather recommend writing two native apps. You'll have more opportunities and later on less problems. However this is more effort than making one hybrid app. But you also need to get familiar with the technologies used by PhoneGap, such as AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use phonegap for phone app. Phonegap is basically a native app with html. Technically saying you use web pages on a phone. Things to note. Phonegap uses javascript,html, optional python or java etc. and they also uses node.js to communicate with a server ( google app engine etc.) I am not very familliar with using node.js I only started it myself.

You may consider using Rest api to do the communication. Use Json or XML.

Just to clarify:

Web apps are websites on your browsers.

Native apps are specifically for phones with no html ( they have their own gui drag and drop with xml etc.)